# reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog producing LoggingEvent not AccessEvent

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, reactive-streams, logstash-logback-encoder

I've been trying to configure spring-boot 2.1 with webflux to store access logs in JSON. Moreover I need to have information like protocol, status code as separate JSON fields (not a part of a message). Looking at the internet I found [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder). Which seems to have everything I need. But during runtime I get following error:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[accessLog] - Appender [accessLog] failed to append. java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.access.spi.IAccessEvent
at java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.access.spi.IAccessEvent
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.accessevent.AccessEventFormattedTimestampJsonProvider.getTimestampAsMillis(AccessEventFormattedTimestampJsonProvider.java:20)
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.FormattedTimestampJsonProvider.writeTo(FormattedTimestampJsonProvider.java:149)
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.JsonProviders.writeTo(JsonProviders.java:77)
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.CompositeJsonFormatter.writeEventToGenerator(CompositeJsonFormatter.java:189)
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.CompositeJsonFormatter.writeEventToOutputStream(CompositeJsonFormatter.java:166)
at  at net.logstash.logback.encoder.CompositeJsonEncoder.encode(CompositeJsonEncoder.java:122)
at  at net.logstash.logback.encoder.CompositeJsonEncoder.encode(CompositeJsonEncoder.java:34)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:230)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:102)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:84)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:270)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:257)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:421)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:591)
at  at reactor.util.Loggers$Slf4JLogger.info(Loggers.java:255)
at  at reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog.log(AccessLog.java:104)
at  at reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLogHandler.lambda$write$0(AccessLogHandler.java:77)
at  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
at  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504)
at  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483)
at  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
at  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:103)
at  at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.trySuccess(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:48)
at  at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeSuccess(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:696)
at  at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:258)
at  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWriteInternal(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:216)
at  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWrite0(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:209)
at  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:397)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934)
at  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901)
at  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1396)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
at  at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533)
at  at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)
at  at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:358)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
at  at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
at  at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
at  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
```

My configuration is fairly simple :

```
<appender name="accessLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/access_log.log</file>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashAccessEncoder"/>
</appender>

<logger name="reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="accessLog"/>
</logger>
```

At this point I got stuck. I've been searching internet and looking into logback code but still I have no idea what to do to have AccessEvent which contains much more information, instead of LoggingEvent

Answer (score 1):

The `LogstashAccessEncoder` from logstash-logback-encoder requires [logback-access](https://logback.qos.ch/access.html), which provides AccessEvents.  logback-access is only available for jetty and tomcat.  It is not available for reactor-netty.

Reactor-netty's `reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog` just uses a standard log event (not an AccessEvent).  So, if you want to use logstash-logback-encoder, you would use a `LogstashEncoder` instead of a `LogstashAccessEncoder`, like this:

```xml
<appender name="accessLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/access_log.log</file>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
</appender>

<logger name="reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="accessLog"/>
</logger>
```

The downside is that `LogstashEncoder` knows nothing about an HTTP request.  It just knows about log events logged via a `Logger`.  Therefore, you cannot configure which HTTP details are logged when using a `LogstashEncoder` like you can when using `LogstashAccessEncoder`.   Instead, your log event will just show the details provided by `reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog` as part of the log message. The details will not be available as separate fields in the JSON output.  Although, since logstash-logback-encoder is extremely customizable, you could write a [custom `JsonProvider`](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#custom-json-provider) that parsed the log message from `reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog` and split it out into separate JSON fields.